# In JavaScript, why does the blur method trigger a blur event, but the submit method does not trigger a submit event?

Tags: javascript, dom

I was thinking of forcing an onblur handler to run by calling the element's blur method. But then, I thought it wouldn't work, because I remembered that calling submit on a FormElement does not cause its onsubmit method to be run.

After some experimentation, I found that calling blur does cause the element's onblur handler to get called. This seems very inconsistent, not that it surprises me (this is JS after all). Still, if there's a good reason for this, I'd like to know. Is there a good reason to call the handler in the case of blur but not submit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree it seems inconsistent.  My take is that OnSubmit behavior has a ton of legacy baggage because much of its functionality was designed so that people could code right inside of form elements.  To this end onsubmit was used to validate input without cracking open a source editor or javascript file.  My guess is that when they coded this behavior (a long time ago), this seemed wise because once you are in javascript the programmer can easily validate the input themselves so the automatic check isn't necessary.  Seems like an oversight to me.

This following website on quirksmode specifically warns of this, so clearly many people are being confused by this.

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/forms.html